Dart (Dead Code) in a conditional statment
Am new to dart learning more about dart.
for tenary opertors in below code, else is considered a dead code.
// conditional expressions
  bool isPublic = true;
  var visibility = isPublic ? "public" : "private";
  print(visibility);

This also happens in the if statement, not sure why dart liner considers the else statement as a dead code.
when i run the dart analyze, feedback as bellow.
Analyzing operators.dart...            0.2s

warning • operators.dart:37:42 • Dead code. Try removing the code, or fixing the code before it so that it can be reached. • dead_code

1 issue found.



This is not dart specific. isPublic variable defined as true. And then there is nothing in the code that could change it's value before IF statement so visibility variable is always gonna be "public".

@Batu.Khan, if you were to convert your comment to an answer, I would upvote it and the OP would have the option to accept it.

isPublic variable is locally scoped and is assigned a constant value of true and the linter knows that you are not reassigning it before the if clause so it warns that isPublic is always ```true`` hence the else condition never gets executed.
The warning will be gone when you assign isPublic dynamically.
